# How to decide whether a stock opening price is more or less equal to its closing price as compared to intraday price action

Tags: stocks, statistics

I want to study how many times a certain stock market index (e.g. DJI, DAX) historically had approximately the same opening and closing price, i.e. relative to the action price during the very same day. That is, the likelihood of whether a certain stock market index closed at the same price as the opening price, regardless of the action inbetween.

I have already computed the relative difference between the opening and closing prices. But how to compare this with the intraday volatility?

I have access to opening price, closing price, highest price and lowest price for each stock market index for the last 20 years. Are these data sufficient for an analysis, and any ideas as how to perform this analysis? Links, technical explanations etc. are most welcome.

Comment: I had to downvote for this troubling sentence: *"In other words, I would like to set up some statistics which tells me about the likelihood of whether a certain stock market index will close at the same price as the opening price, regardless of the action inbetween."* Please please please be aware that historical relationships of price could bear no resemblance to future relationships of price. Don't get in over your head.

Comment: thank you, OP corrected

Comment: The general idea is to find a pattern or relationship in the data, formularize that pattern and then backtest it. Even if someone knew of such a relationship and it was functional, why would anyone disclose it? Yes, profitable strategies can be found but they are often fleeting. Crunch your numbers to see if you can find one. Many millions of others have tried. Maybe you'll get lucky. 20 years of data is well more than sufficient for an analysis. And regarding your title, I would guess that the close will be higher than the open far more in bull markets and vice versa.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we have to firmly say that this site simply IS NOT for discussing stock charting ideas.

Comment: @Fattie Ok, any ideas as where to put this question then?

Comment: @BobBaerker it is not an answer to 'free money' or anything like that. But, for me, an interesting hypothesis to examine :)

Comment: Welcome new user, As mentioned on a number of similar questions, it is truly a "discussion".  So, which muscle car is the best one .. discussion for some car discussion site.  Discuss some stock trading idea .. discussion for some stock trading discussion site. You COULD try the quant SE site, but they will likely just dismiss it as either trivial or a discussion I'm afraid

Comment: https://quant.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Fattie - While it's true that the ultimate goal of the question might be to develop a trading strategy, it's not one about stock charting ideas.  The OP is asking about the probability (umm, math?) of price closing higher or lower based on a set of open/high/low/close numbers (umm, math?) that print during daily trading.

Comment: @User4536124 - "An answer to free money"? I don't have an issue with your question.  Trading strategies begin with a germ of an idea, aka an interesting hypothesis,  and then through rigorous analysis, they are put to the test, which few survive.  Decades ago I spent many years analyzing data and it took years to evolve some approaches to trading that offered higher probability of success.  So I encourage you to continue to do what this question is all about.

Comment: @BobBaerker , for sure, note that I just used "charting" loosely, once. Like I dun did seds: *"Discuss some stock trading idea .. discussion for some stock trading discussion site."*

Comment: @Fattie - Fer sure, the OP dun did not seds anything bout stok trading ideas.  I think he did ask: "Are these **data** sufficient for an **analysis**?"  Yours truly, Sigh On Narra.

Comment: I retracted my close vote anyways, since it has intertest !!  @BobBaerker

Comment: @BobBaerker yes, really just math. The relative difference, import of csv files etc. are done in Matlab. Most likely somebody else have looked at this problem beforehand - and most likely with a stock market (finance) background? I am thinking about applying rms to the inbetween values, so to get a weighing factor, but still undecided...